# Bazel project + Tensorflow dependency trouble

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, bazel

I've stuck while trying to connect Tensorflow package with Bazel build system.
I have such configurations
**BUILD**

```
cc_binary(
    name = "basic_neural",
    srcs = ["src/main.cc"],
    deps = [
        "@org_tensorflow//tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc"
    ],
)
```

**WORKSPACE**

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "org_tensorflow",
    sha256 = "59912218ca58daf114f72a3aa45e2c8c47781a7bfa4f8811b685f4ac67d1d244",
    url = "https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/archive/r2.7.tar.gz",
)
```

**Error log**

```
ERROR: /path/to/project/basic_neural/BUILD:1:10: no such package '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow': BUILD file not found in directory 'tensorflow' of external repository @org_tensorflow. Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package. and referenced by '//:basic_neural'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:basic_neural' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.095s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (11 packages loaded, 18 targets configured)
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (11 packages loaded, 18 targets configured)
```